# Package ‘randomForest ’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

Tags: r

`package ‘randomForest ’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)`

How can I get this kind of "not available" message, since I know for sure that `randomForest` exists? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to upload old version of random forest

```
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages
```

you can find the old sources

```
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/
```

Answer (score 25):

1. Go to

```
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/
```

2. Right-click version of choice and select "Copy Link Location"

```
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/randomForest_4.6-12.tar.gz
```

3. Store link location in a variable called `urlPackage` in R

```
urlPackage <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/randomForest_4.6-12.tar.gz"
```

4. Finally, use `install.packages`

```
install.packages(urlPackage, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Hope this works for you. Take care.

Comment: Which part did not work? Part-1, Part-2, Part-3, or Part-4? Please be specific as to what you mean by "Did not work for package named `rbokeh`".

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. No matter what version I try to install, I get an error like:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran

Answer (score 0):

Michael's solution above should normally work for most people. I tried it but still faced the same issue.

Upgrading to the latest version of R i.e. R (4.1.2) solved the issue for me.

This release has the pre-built package. I hope this helps.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/